# Problem with luabind installation under Windows

Tags: windows, installation, luabind

Cant build luabind. Have downloaded Boost and bjam.exe. Have anybody experience for it under Windows? How i can use this library? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use my branch of luabind, which includes a cmake-based build system which may be easier for you. https://github.com/rpavlik/luabind

Comment: You're my hero, @rpavlik! Needed a MinGW build, this worked like a charm. It would be nice if Windows binaries were just available, but you can't have everything. Cheers.